# Ant task: In ant build i am using java task, where i used system.out.println which are not appearing in the eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

```
<java classname="GenerateLuaFromDDL"  
classpathref="project.classpath" failonerror="true">  
<argline="'${build.databases.client.dir}/SQLiteDDL.ddl''${build.client.dir}'${ClientLuaGenFile}''lua'"/>  
</java>
```

How to get java system.out.println in eclipse console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify **output** attribute of the java task which will redirect your error and output streams to the file specified as the value of this attribute.
Or

You can explore the **echo** task in Ant through which you will be able to print the messages on the console

More information can be found on :

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html. or

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheAnt/article.html